# Run Docker container for backend server code together with Nginx for React frontend code on same port 80

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 instance already running my Docker container containing my MongoDB and Apache Maven backend code. The Docker container is successfully running on port 80, and queries to it are working. I'm trying to set up Nginx as well to load my React generated index.html from "npm run build". However, Nginx cannot start itself because it can't bind to port 80 as expected. I've tried to proxy by setting

```
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header  Host       $http_host;
proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:3000;
```

but it doesn't seem to quite do the trick. Do I need to stop Docker, and re-run it with a different syntax? I've seen `8080:80` on some other online resources instead of `80:80`. Is there anything I should fix with my Nginx config file?

Also, when I make calls to the backend via Axios in React, should I set the base URL to be `0.0.0.0:<SERVER_PORT>`, or should I set it to something like `<PUBLIC_EC2_INSTANCE_URL>:<SERVER_PORT>`, or something else entirely?

Any help or advice is appreciated; thanks for your time!

Comment: Your host machine is already binding port 80 to a different container (mongodb?).  Only one of your containers can bind to that host port.  You need to choose one of the two containers to run on the host's port 80.  What port in your mongodb container are you binding to 80 on your host?  The standard mongodb port is 27017.  I would bind my host port 80 to the nginx container port 80 (e.g. `-p 80:80`) and then I would bind host port 27017 to 27017 in mongodb (e.g. `-p 27017:27017`).  See the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking) on port binding.

Comment: As far as the URL goes, you should set it to the Route 53 DNS name that points at your EC2 instance; not an IP address, and not the special 0.0.0.0 "everywhere" address.